# GMap API FT click event returning mouseEvent is null

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a Fusion Table with about 2000 rows displayed via the GMap API.
This has been working well for quite a few months in development.

The FT layer does it's own custom InfoWindow so I add an event Listener for mouse clicks.

It went live today and suddenly, after a few hours, probably with greatly increased usage, my event Listen is reporting:
"mouseEvent is null"

What's also true is that even when accessed thru the Google FT UI, when the map is visualized click events are no longer working either.

I've confirmed that a using a different FT in the existing app, fixes the problem.

So I'm convinced that I'm hitting some kind of usage limit.
Unfortunately I have not yet upgraded to the new FT API

Has anyone else experienced this?

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=2482072

http://p5.neracoos.org/IOOSCatalog3/rcv_ft_frame.html

**UPDATE**

Just wanted to follow up on this post.
This problem seems to have disappeared so I need to apologize for my panic.
Still have no idea what caused the problem but the application is working fine now.

http://www.ioos.gov/catalog/welcome.html

Eric

Comment: Have you tried specifying a different version of the Google Maps API v3 (other than the [development version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning)?

Comment: Is it possible that you hit the 25'000 requests per user limit? Did you check the API console?

Comment: Thanks geocodezip and Odi for the suggestions.  Strangely the problem disappeared over the weekend, which might confirm my usage limits suspicion or not. I'll continue to monitor it and see if the problem re-occurs.